# Magento1: Cart price rule for free shipping if subtotal incl. tax is over a limit

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping, tax-calculation, subtotal

Does anyone know of a patch or extension with that I can create a cart price rule that sets free shipping if subtotal (INCL. tax) is over a certain limit?

It (still) seems to do comparison  only using subtotal without tax.

> My Settings are: Prices in the catalog are including tax, Apply
>   Customer Class before Discount, Apply Discount on Prices incl. Tax.

If I create a cart price rule with **Subtotal >= 19.90**, this will work only if I put items that have subtotal without tax of **19.90**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to switch to Subtotal incl. Tax. This can be done here

```
System->Configuration->Tax->Shopping Cart Display Settings->Display Subtotal
```

Beware switching over to *subtotal incl. tax*. It will affect totals in frontend.

Comment: It is already set to display including tax. In the frontend is all ok. The cart price seems always to compare against subtotal without tax.

Comment: check whether it has the same effect on logged-in customer with default address. It may be caused by missing customer quote object